# Spring beans and changing bean parameter in application life cycle

Tags: java, spring

I have a web application that is based on Spring. There is defined a bean that holds some class `MyClass` that is passed also with beans to `MyEndpoint` that `extends AbstractMarshallingPayloadEndpoint`.

`MyClass` has set some boolean parameter in beans to `true`.

If my application will change this parameter programically to false, does next request will have it also set to `false` or it will contains a default bean parameter - `true` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the `scope` of the bean (which will default to `singleton`, if you don't specify one).

1. If it is of `singleton` scope, there is one instance of that bean in the application context, and each time you ask for that bean, you get that single instance.  If you change it in a request with this scope, then the change will be maintained.
2. If it is of `prototype` scope, a new instance is given to you (created with the same parameters) each time you ask the application context for it.  If you change it in a request with this scope, then the change will be ignored when you get another instance of this object.

These are the two most commonly used (at least with my time in Spring).  There are other scopes (request, session, globalsession), but you should read the [documentation on them that Spring provides](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

Answer (score 0):

If you want this property to change dynamically according to your application business logic and not only to be reset on every new request (otherwise Request scope will do the magic) consider Factory Methods (especially [Lookup Method Injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html))